# SAP B1 System Form newly added components on UI not showing when debugging

Tags: c#, sapb1

I am developing an add-on in SAP b1 (10.00.160). Recently I added some text boxes and labels on a User form. But those components are not showing when debugging the addon. When debugging, inside the **OnInitializeComponent()** method, below error comes with the newly added components.

*An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in SAPBusinessOneSDK.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Item - Invalid item  [66000-3]. Form Unique Id: 'UDEV000003', Item Unique Id: 'txtNPC'*

Note that the UniqueID of the component is **txtNPC** and it's showing in the System Form UI component properties. I'm using VS 2015 for this development.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are the text box items added through the visual studio Designer or with code?

Comment: Through visual studio

Comment: can you add the code from  OnInitializeComponent()  in your question  ?